# ListPicker expanded mode needs double tap to select WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

This issue sounds very similar to the others suggested, but I don't see it mentioned elsewhere.

My ListPicker is hosted inside a scrollviewer and a few items are added to it in design. since it's just 5 items (Title), it needs to expand - but it doesnt seem to. I need to manually regiter an event on Tap to Open() the control. once it's open , it needs to be doubletapped to close. is there a way I can prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same behavior in August build.
February toolkit doesn't have this issue, so if you can't to continue development with this bug, you could use an old one.

Comment: I'm using too many controls from the October build, cannot revert back unfortunately.

Comment: They provide sources, so you can copy listpicker to your project and use it with your toolkit simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, will try to get the february version then.

Comment: JeffWilcox of the Toolkit also said that the November build has a fix. should try it out and update this question.